# I need help about regex php

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php
$regex = '<p>ttt<p>';

if (preg_match('#<p>[a-z]<p>#i', $regex, $result))
{
    echo 'True';
    echo $result[0];
}
else
{
    echo 'False';
}

?>
```

Basically, this code give me False. However, if I replace `[a-z]` by  `[a-z]*` the code give me true.

Or, if I keep  `[a-z]` without `*`, but I remove `<p><p>` in the `preg_match`, the code give me true.

Honestly, I don't understand why the first give me false and the others true. Can anyone explain me why ?

Comment: `ragex` - an angry regex?

Answer (score 2):

`[a-z]` is, believe it or not, considered one character.  Just like if I put `[ab]`, that would be "one character" too.  `[a-z]` *means* that character can be any letter: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.  When we add `[a-z]*` we are now allowing that one character of `[a-z]` to have 0 or more repetitions.

```
<?php
$regex = '<p>ttt<p>';

if (preg_match('#<p>[a-z]*<p>#i', $regex, $result))
{
    echo 'True';
    echo $result[0];
}
else
{
    echo 'False';
}

?>
```

Check out the results here:

https://eval.in/753902

Comment: Hey, thanks to try to help me. I was really busy.

Basically, "ttt" = 3 characters, right ?

I'm still not sure why https://eval.in/759585 give me true.

Answer (score 0):

`[a-z]` catches only one character while `[a-z]*` catch characters length upto 0 to n.

And your pattern should be encapsulated by `/`

```
/<p>[a-z]*<p>/i
```

Comment: The `#` is a valid delimiter.

Comment: @chris85, Thanks for the information I didn't know this

Comment: You can see more here, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. `A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.` Some characters are better than others, depends on the string.

Answer (score 0):

I posted few days ago another question as comment.

I'll ask as post.

If [a-z] is considered one character.

```html
 <?php
$regex = '<p>ttt<p>';
 
if (preg_match('/<p>[a-z]<p>/i', $regex, $result))
{
 echo 'True';
 echo $result[0];
}
else
{
 echo 'False';
}
 
?>
```

Give me false, because 'ttt' is basically 3 characters, right ?

However,

```html
<?php
$regex = '<p>ttt<p>';
 
if (preg_match('/[a-z]/i', $regex, $result))
{
 echo 'True';
 echo $result[0];
}
else
{
 echo 'False';
}
 
?>
```

this code give me true, but the string above is basically 9 characters.